# Error occurred while installing openstack : ./stack.sh:137:die

Tags: git, ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I tried installing openstack through devstack using the following commands

> $ git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b
>   stable/havana devstack/

i followed [this](http://blog.ravihansa3000.com/2014/04/installing-openstack-on-ubuntu-1204-lts.html) link to do it.

I try to run stack.sh using:-

```
 thushara@ubuntu:~/devstack$ ./stack.sh
```

Result:-

```
WARNING: this script has not been tested on trusty
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:137:die
```

how to set FORCE=yes? How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try and set this variable:

```
FORCE=yes ./stack.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply and it helped me a lot!
but i uncounted another error please be kind enough to support that question as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832153/error-occurred-while-installing-openstack-after-setting-force-yes