# Error occurred while installing openstack after setting FORCE=yes

Tags: git, ubuntu, openstack, apt-get, devstack

I tried installing openstack through devstack using the following commands

> $ git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b
>   stable/havana devstack/

i followed [this](http://blog.ravihansa3000.com/2014/04/installing-openstack-on-ubuntu-1204-lts.html) link to do it.

In my first attempt i got a error and I resolved it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830324/error-occurred-while-installing-openstack) link.

As per the solution i ran below command:-

```
thushara@ubuntu:~/devstack$ FORCE=yes ./stack.sh
```

Then the script executed but after some time it throws and error again. kindly find segments of the error log below.

```
thushara@ubuntu:~/devstack$ FORCE=yes ./stack.sh
WARNING: this script has not been tested on trusty
APT::Acquire::Retries "20";
Using mysql database backend
2014-09-12 14:58:54.958 | + echo_summary 'Installing package prerequisites'
2014-09-12 14:58:54.966 | + [[ -t 3 ]]
2014-09-12 14:58:54.966 | + [[ True != \T\r\u\e ]]
...
2014-09-12 14:58:55.084 | +++ IFS='     
2014-09-12 14:58:55.084 | '
2014-09-12 14:58:55.084 | ++ install_package bridge-utils pylint python-setuptools screen unzip wget psmisc git lsof openssh-server openssl vim-nox locate python-virtualenv python-unittest2 iputils-ping wget curl tcpdump euca2ools tar gcc libxml2-dev python-dev python-eventlet python-routes python-greenlet python-sqlalchemy python-wsgiref python-pastedeploy python-xattr python-iso8601 python-dev python-lxml python-pastescript python-pastedeploy python-paste sqlite3 python-pysqlite2 python-sqlalchemy python-mysqldb python-webob python-greenlet python-routes libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev python-dateutil msgpack-python dnsmasq-base dnsmasq-utils kpartx parted iputils-arping python-mysqldb python-xattr python-lxml gawk iptables ebtables sqlite3 sudo libjs-jquery-tablesorter vlan curl genisoimage socat python-mox python-paste python-migrate python-gflags python-greenlet python-libxml2 python-routes python-numpy python-pastedeploy python-eventlet python-cheetah python-carrot python-tempita python-sqlalchemy python-suds python-lockfile python-m2crypto python-boto python-kombu python-feedparser python-iso8601 nbd-client lvm2 open-iscsi genisoimage sysfsutils sg3-utils tgt lvm2 qemu-utils libpq-dev python-dev open-iscsi python-numpy python-beautifulsoup python-dateutil python-paste python-pastedeploy python-anyjson python-routes python-xattr python-sqlalchemy python-webob python-kombu pylint python-eventlet python-nose python-sphinx python-mox python-kombu python-coverage python-cherrypy3 python-migrate nodejs libxslt1-dev
2014-09-12 14:58:55.084 | ++ is_ubuntu
2014-09-12 14:58:55.084 | ++ [[ -z deb ]]
...
2014-09-12 14:58:55.085 | ++ sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= apt-get --option Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold --assume-yes update
2014-09-12 14:59:35.138 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 |   
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 |   
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 |   
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 | Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
2014-09-12 14:59:35.139 |   
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 | Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 |   Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
2014-09-12 14:59:35.140 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:36.968 | Reading package lists...
2014-09-12 14:59:36.971 | W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
2014-09-12 14:59:36.972 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.972 | W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  
2014-09-12 14:59:36.974 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.974 | W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  
2014-09-12 14:59:36.974 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.975 | W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  
2014-09-12 14:59:36.975 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.975 | W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:36.975 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.976 | W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:36.976 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.976 | W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:36.976 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.976 | W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 14:59:36.976 | 
2014-09-12 14:59:36.977 | W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
2014-09-12 14:59:36.977 | ++ NO_UPDATE_REPOS=True
...
2014-09-12 14:59:36.993 | Reading package lists...
2014-09-12 14:59:37.221 | Building dependency tree...
2014-09-12 14:59:37.222 | Reading state information...
2014-09-12 14:59:37.487 | bridge-utils is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.487 | curl is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.487 | gawk is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.488 | git is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.488 | iptables is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.488 | lsof is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.489 | lvm2 is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.489 | parted is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.489 | psmisc is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.489 | python is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.490 | screen is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.490 | sudo is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.490 | tar is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.490 | tcpdump is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.490 | wget is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.491 | openssh-server is already the newest version.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.491 | openssh-server set to manually installed.
2014-09-12 14:59:37.491 | The following extra packages will be installed:
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   binutils build-essential comerr-dev cpp cpp-4.8 docutils-common docutils-doc
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   dpkg-dev fakeroot fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core g++ g++-4.8 gcc-4.8
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   javascript-common krb5-multidev libaio1 libalgorithm-diff-perl
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan0 libatomic1
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   libblas3 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libc-ares2 libc-dev-bin
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   libc6 libc6-dev libcloog-isl4 libconfig-general-perl libdpkg-perl
2014-09-12 14:59:37.492 |   libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libfontconfig1
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libgcc-4.8-dev libgfortran3 libgmp10 libgomp1 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libibverbs1 libisl10 libitm1 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libjs-jquery-hotkeys libjs-jquery-isonscreen libjs-jquery-metadata
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libk5crypto3 libkadm5clnt-mit9
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-7 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblapack3 liblcms2-2
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   liblua5.2-0 libmnl0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmysqlclient18
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libpaper-utils
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libpaper1 libperl5.18 libpq5 libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev libquadmath0
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   librabbitmq1 librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1 libruby1.9.1 libsgutils2-2
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libsysfs2 libtcl8.6
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libtidy-0.99-0 libtiff5 libtk8.6 libtsan0 libv8-3.14.5 libwebp5 libwebpmux1
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   libxft2 libxml2 libxrender1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libyaml-0-2 linux-libc-dev
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   make manpages-dev mysql-common python-amqp python-amqplib python-astroid
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   python-colorama python-decorator python-dingus python-distlib python-dns
2014-09-12 14:59:37.493 |   python-docutils python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools
2014-09-12 14:59:37.494 |   python-formencode python-html5lib python-jinja2 python-librabbitmq
2014-09-12 14:59:37.494 |   python-logilab-common python-markupsafe python-openid python-pastedeploy-tpl
2014-09-12 14:59:37.494 |   python-pbr python-pil python-pip python-pygments python-repoze.lru
2014-09-12 14:59:37.494 |   python-requestbuilder python-roman python-scgi python-sqlalchemy-ext
2014-09-12 14:59:37.494 |   python-stompy python-tk python-utidylib python-yaml python2.7-dev ruby
2014-09-12 14:59:37.494 |   ruby1.9.1 sharutils sphinx-common sphinx-doc x11-common zlib1g-dev
...
2014-09-12 15:00:17.619 | 9 upgraded, 207 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
2014-09-12 15:00:17.619 | Need to get 95.9 MB of archives.
2014-09-12 15:00:17.619 | After this operation, 322 MB of additional disk space will be used.
2014-09-12 15:00:17.620 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
2014-09-12 15:00:17.620 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:17.621 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaio1 amd64 0.3.109-4
2014-09-12 15:00:17.621 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:17.622 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libasan0 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
2014-09-12 15:00:17.622 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:17.622 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libatomic1 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
2014-09-12 15:00:17.622 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:17.623 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libboost-system1.54.0 amd64 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1
2014-09-12 15:00:17.623 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:17.624 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libboost-thread1.54.0 amd64 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1
2014-09-12 15:00:17.624 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:17.624 | Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgmp10 amd64 2:5.1.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1
2014-09-12 15:00:17.624 |   Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
...
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nodejs/nodejs_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-iso8601/python-iso8601_0.1.10-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-lockfile/python-lockfile_0.8-2ubuntu2_all.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-mox/python-mox_0.5.3-3build1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-webob/python-webob_1.3.1-1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/socat/socat_1.7.2.3-1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.717 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sysfsutils/sysfsutils_2.1.0+repack-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.718 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.718 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vim/vim-nox_7.4.052-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.718 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.718 | E: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vlan/vlan_1.9-3ubuntu10_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
2014-09-12 15:00:57.718 | 
2014-09-12 15:00:57.719 | E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
2014-09-12 15:00:57.719 | +++ failed
2014-09-12 15:00:57.719 | +++ local r=100
2014-09-12 15:00:57.719 | ++++ jobs -p
2014-09-12 15:00:57.719 | +++ kill
2014-09-12 15:00:57.719 | stack.sh failed: full log in /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log.2014-09-12-202854
```

some text are omitted(...) looks like this error cause

> Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'

How to overcome above error. I tried installing,

> apt-get update

In the root console and end up getting the same error,

```
thushara@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i
root@ubuntu:~# 
root@ubuntu:~# 
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get update
Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                           

Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                   

Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                 

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                    

Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                         
  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can somebody help me to overcome these errors! I just want to Install OpenStack on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with DevStack.

Comment: See if https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed could help, adding a line in  /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: do you mean running the commands using -proposed attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer!

The solution to this problem goes as follows:

Step 1: Go to System –> Preferences –> Network Connections.

Step 2: Next, select your default Network Interface (eth0) and click ‘Edit’.

Step 3: Then select ‘IPv4 Settings’ and choose ‘Automatic (DHCP) addresses only’.

Step 4: Next, enter the new DNS server addresses in the ‘DNS servers’ box. Use commas to separate multiple addresses and click ‘Apply’ to save.

Step 5: Choose your preferred DNS details

```
OpenDNS           --->  208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220              
Google Public DNS --->  8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4                 
Comodo Secure DNS --->  156.154.70.22, 156.154.71.22
```

After configuring, check to make sure it is working by going online.

For full step-by-step tutorial for solving similar problems please check:
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/08/change-dns-information-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/

The above link explains how to change the DNS Settings in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it occurs when there is a lot of high usage on your home network and update manager has a hard time contacting the server.

Try again after a few minutes and I think you will find it will be resolved.

Comment: yes that was the issue. After i try this out in some other network it works!

Answer (score 0):

The main Error is `Could not resolve 'lk.archive.ubuntu.com'`

So issue this command in server `ping lk.archive.ubuntu.com`. You will get it's IP. Set this IP and domain in `/etc/hosts/` . Hence you can reduce this error.

```
   IP  lk.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export proxy.

```
export http_proxy=http://<IP>:<PORT>
export https_proxy=https://<IP>:<PORT>
```

Also point your pip to correct url for packages.

```
vim /home/<user>/.pip/pip.conf

[global]
index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```